# Zero to one proportion data, with quadratic term?

Tags: r, nonlinear-regression, proportion

I have a data set with the following:

N = 60;
x = developmental stage (range 25 to 44);
y = proportion of 10 minute trial performing a behavior (range 0 to 0.81; 30 zeros)

A scatterplot produces a quadratic looking curve where those in mid-development clearly performed the behavior for more time. Most of the zeros are in the youngest and oldest individuals. If I break up the data into 5 groups according to developmental stage, an ANOVA/Tukey strongly supports this pattern. However, I would like to analyze this data continuously without breaking it into groups.

I have considered arcsine square root transformed proportion data in a linear regression, but I am unsure if that can incorporate a quadratic term, and this analysis results in a very small R squared value (less than 0.1). I have also considered arcsine square root transformed proportion data in a GLM containing a quadratic term or a beta regression (zeros??), but am not sure where to go from here.

I am planning to say in the paper that the individuals in mid-development perform the behavior more than those in early or late development, but am struggling to interpret the data in a way that supports that statement.

I appreciate any suggestions, thank you!

Comment: I would consider a finite mixture model with one part being 0 vs not 0 and the other part being among those with more than 0. In `SAS` this can be done fairly straightforwardly with the (new) `PROC FMM`. In `R` the package `flexmix` can be used.